# Notification Access Android? How to use it?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I see that apps can request to have Notification Access which states that they can dismiss app notifcation and stuff like that. But what does that mean? Like how would one go about dismissing app notifications and stuff like that within your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the NotificationListenerService [added in Android 4.3](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener). With it you can listen to new notifications being posted, and manage them, including dismissing them. You can find the documentation **[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)**.

To dismiss a notification, for example, you would call the `cancelNotification` method, and provide it with the key, that you previously got from the getKey() method, of a notification. These notification objects can be obtained by calling the `getActiveNotifications()` method.